# Getting errors after shifting live site to local

Tags: magento

```
 Warning: include(Mage/Core/Model/App.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/sitename/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Core/Model/App.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/sitename/app/code/local:/var/www/html/sitename/app/code/community:/var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core:/var/www/html/sitename/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/sitename/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_App' not found in /var/www/html/sitename/app/Mage.php on line 589
```

I have tried vhost also, but getting same errors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update dependencies with composer?

`cd /var/www/html/sitename/
composer update`

Could also be useful to check db settings table for any absolute roots.

Comment: Ole, thanks for answering
there is no absolute root in db, if there exist absolute path, i used same vhost url as live site has

Comment: When I think about it, it could be related to file/folder rights. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Comment: Warning: include(Mage/Core/Model/App.php) 
there is no app.php file in core folder, seems like it causes errors, but surprisingly live working fine without having app.php file in core.

Comment: Found a similar thread; http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/remove-local-core-changes-after-testing